# TCL replace ^ in string

Tags: string, search, replace, tcl

I'm trying to carry out a strip of an unwanted character from a string in TCL.

My string contains a carat symbol (^), which i need to strip out.

However, i suspect that the ^ may need to be handle differently (possibly escaped?), as when i search using STRING FIRST, i get an output of "-1" (ie false/doesnt exist).

I know i'm doing the right thing because if i do a STRING FIRST on another charachter, i get the expected position as an output.

```
STRING: "<^abs"
Intended output: "<abs"
```

```
set pos [string first "^" $STRING]
set replaced_string [string replace $STRING $pos $pos ""]
puts $replaced_string
```

The problem specifically relates to line one of the above code. As previously discribed, the output of $pos is -1 even those the ^ exists

Comment: [Looks like `$pos` is `1` and the replacement works well](https://ideone.com/PXVDDP).

Comment: That is what i would expect, but the application i'm using this is, which uses TCL as a scripting language is what is giving my the outcome described above. Thanks for your help.

Back to the drawing board

Comment: Then you did not provide enough data about the issue. What app are you using it in?

Comment: Apologies for that, i did not realise that the application would've handled things in a different way before relaying my string to the TCL Script.

The application i was running this from within is Cloverleaf Integration Suite, as detailed my own answer below.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems what i was trying to do, strictly speaking is correct in pure-TCL.

The reason this was not working was that the application I was using ([Cloverleaf Integration Suite](http://www.infor.com/product-summary/healthcare/cloverleaf/) by [Infor](http://www.infor.com)) - which makes use of TCL as a scripting language  - was carrying out it's own "processing" prior to parsing the strings into my TCL script.

Thanks for the help provided though.

Answer (score 1):

Considering your STRING as "`<^abs`", your code works well and replaces. 
Alternatively you can do

```
set replaced_string [string map {"^" ""} $STRING]
```

Comment: The `string map` is exactly what I'd do.

Comment: OP: note that `string map` replaces *all* occurrences of a string, not just the first. If only the first should be replaced, `string replace` or `regsub` are better.